# Populating a ListView from a SQLite database in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to populate a ListView in a separate class with data taken from a SQLite database held in another class. What would be the easiest way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a Cursor eg: `getList()` from your other class to the current ListView class.

```
objItem = new Contacts(this);

this.cur = objItem.getList();
this.startManagingCursor(this.cur);

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cur,
        new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1});

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

in class you have a method returning Cursor

```
public Cursor getList() {
        // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content
        // provider.
        Uri contacts = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        // Make the query.
        ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
        // Form an array specifying which columns to return.
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };

        Cursor managedCursor = cr.query(contacts, projection, null, null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        return managedCursor;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks again Pentium10, would I be able to use this code even if I have not implemented a Content Provider?

Comment: I've just copy pasted this. You use a `Cursor cur=db.query(...)` method and return the Cursor variable.

Comment: @Pentium10 can you solve this problem i need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435531/android-setting-sqlite-database-values-in-an-listview