# Listview filling from database

Tags: android, android-activity

good evening , I need  help about filling a list view from a MySQL Database,
i don't know how to do it becaus i'm beginner in android 
i wanna icon  and 3 text views the first is title bold and the second is the RIB  and the last one is in the bottom and right of the list view

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating a ListView from a SQLite database in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515375/populating-a-listview-from-a-sqlite-database-in-android)

Comment: you could have used google for this and would have found many post/blogs with lot of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit too generic and not clearly defined.  That's probably why it got down voted.  I'd say your best bet is to start with the documentation. Start by reading about [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) and possibly [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) and try it yourself.  If you still have problems, ask a specific question about something you don't understand or can't get working.  The best specific answer I can give is that you will need to define a custom adapter to create the item view you want.  You will most likely want a layout xml for that item view.

Comment: Probably should have been a comment on the original question.

Comment: @stkent I was going to at first. It started off as a comment but then I added what I figured was the best answer I could think of for the question.  Oh well, hopefully it's enough to help the OP.